# How to differentiate between RAM and heap usage in logstash?

Tags: kubernetes, logstash, logstash-configuration, kubernetes-pod, elk

I am running a logstash Kubernetes pod, I have set LS_JVM_OPTS := -Xmx1g -Xms500m, and monitoring the same using Prometheus grafana, I see memory usage 3.2 Gig. May I know what is happening here?

Comment: What exactly does "memory usage" mean? There are different types of memory that kernel reports, which of those do you really mean?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably seeing the container memory used and not the heap size, there are other things [in the JVM](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/jvm-settings.html#heap-size) like the GC that require memory. Although, `3.2G` seems a bit excessive for that heap , so you might want to check  that the logstash JVM does indeed have those heap options.

```sh
$ kubectl exec -t <pod-name> -c <container-name> -- /bin/ps -Af | grep java
```

You can also check ️ what [request/limits](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/) you have in your container, to see if you are requesting 3.2Gb initially.

```sh
kubectl get pod <logstash-pod-name> -c <container-name> -o=yaml
```